# Django Celery Scrappy ОШИБКА: twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Tags: python, django, scrapy, celery

У меня есть схема:
Command 'collect_positions' (collect_positions.py) -> Celery task (tasks.py) -> ScrappySpider (MySpider) ...

collect_positions.py:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from tracker.models import Keyword
from tracker.tasks import positions


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'collect_positions'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        def chunks(l, n):
            """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
            for i in range(0, len(l), n):
                yield l[i:i + n]

        chunk_size = 1

        keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(product=product).values_list('id', flat=True)

        chunks_list = list(chunks(keywords, chunk_size))
        positions.chunks(chunks_list, 1).apply_async(queue='collect_positions')

        return 0
```

tasks.py:

```
from app_name.celery import app
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy_app import settings as scrapy_settings
from scrapy_app.spiders.my_spider import MySpider
from tracker.models import Keyword
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


@app.task
def positions(*args):
    s = Settings()
    s.setmodule(scrapy_settings)

    keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(id__in=list(args))
    process = CrawlerProcess(s)
    process.crawl(MySpider, keywords_chunk=keywords)
    process.start()

    return 1
```

Я запускаю команду через командную строку, которая создает очереди для парсинга. Первая очередь завершается успешно, но все следующие возвращают ошибку:

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как я могу исправить эту ошибку?
Я могу предоставить любые данные, если в этом будет необходимость...

Comment: попробуйте установить CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1